# Loading new dygraph chart without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load a new dygraph chart without reloading the page. Currently, I am using code like:

```
window.location.href = "newurl.html"
```

to do this, and want to use a similar method without having to reload the url. The new chart will take a new .csv file, and after it is loaded the current chart should be destroyed. Is this even possible or do I have to settle with the function above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a temporary solution that seems to work fine. For those interested, I just used:

```
<ol id="stuff"></ol>
<script>
$( "#stuff" ).load("newurl.html" );
</script>
```

and made this activated by a button click.